# Provisioning profile prefix different than that it compiles with

Tags: ios, xcode, branch, provisioning-profile, deep-linking

I'm running into problems getting Branch to work for deep linking. My thought is it's because of the app prefix.

I go to the developer portal and create a new app id:

[image]

---

Then I create a new provisioning profile using that app id:

[image]

---

When I go to set my prov profile and dev cert the prefix do not match:

[image]

---

So I'm guessing that the app is being compiled with a different prefix than what's in the provisioning profile. So when I try to deep link from Branch, it's not finding the app.

I've tried creating new certificates, new provisioning profiles, new app id's. Nothing fixes this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Alex with Branch here: yes, the provisioning profile mismatch would definitely cause Universal Links not to work! However it shouldn't have any effect on URL scheme deep links. Are both broken right now?

It's tough to troubleshoot exactly where the provisioning profile configuration is off without access to the project file, but here is the Apple docs page about all the places it can be set: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

Comment: thanks so much for getting back to me. I've following through the branch setup directions multiple times and still having issues. This is the only thing that I can think is the problem.

Comment: @random are your URL scheme deep links working? The provisioning profile mismatch isn't part of the Branch configuration so that would need to be resolved separately — have you tried adjusting it with the instructions on that Apple Developer Documentation page?

Comment: yes everything is correct and matching. Would you mind moving to a conversion to help me more? Or should I open a ticket on Branch?

Comment: after some more tweaking the URL scheme does work however the universal links do not. :(

Comment: Excellent! Glad that URL schemes are working...that narrows things down. Could you submit a [support ticket](https://support.branch.io/) for the Universal Links issue? Our support agents will be able to see the backend of your configuration, which should help speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, Universal Links do not work with Branch test keys due to the limit on the size of the AASA file imposed by Apple.

So, if your Universal Links do not work and you're using test keys, that's probably why. Also, make sure that the url you're using doesn't contain /m/ as that's not a Universal Link.