# Team ID Mismatch - does test key still not work in iOS?

Tags: ios, branch.io

I'm setting branch up like this:

```
// Debug settings
Branch.setUseTestBranchKey(true)
Branch.getInstance().setDebug()
branch.validateSDKIntegration()
```

however when `validateSDKIntegration()` gets called I get the indication that my Team ID is invalid. I've double-checked everything and AFAIK everything is right. However I did see another SO question that indicated that test links won't work due to AASA file size limits ( see last answer at [Provisioning profile prefix different than that it compiles with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915775/provisioning-profile-prefix-different-than-that-it-compiles-with) ). Is this possibly my issue?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, go to Dashboard under Settings > Link Settings, in the iOS section next to "Enable Universal Links." They should match your Team ID and Bundle ID. Team ID can be found here https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#accountSummary. Your Bundle ID is found in Xcode, in the General tab for the correct build target. If your Apple App Prefix is different from your Team ID, you should use your App Prefix. Your app prefix can be found from App IDs on Apple's Developer Portal.